# Getting 404 when deploying ASP.Net MVC on Server 2012 and IIS 8

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, windows-server-2012

I've Tried every fix I can find online and none of them have worked.

I added the asp.net 4.5 and 3.5 role to the server.

I added the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests into the web.config

I installed MVC from the asp.net site.  I'm not sure what else needs to be set.

Here's the web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Redacted" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <machineKey validationKey="96820F5717A865002768570C77EC72BBBC16CD2BDBC3D6BD494F4F4734F903FEBDA99E0A694ADB5B2A6D9347FB60BE00F1BF618062DA36C8A378B0B274B80390" decryptionKey="71AA018320CA48F100A58E38285B3AEE7C2E21001C1ASDD1" validation="SHA1" />
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="default.aspx" />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="iisstart.htm" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the 404 message as well as how your IIS install settings look?  For example, my settings look like this: [settings screenshot](http://imgur.com/0gO8Qqu)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what component is issuing the 404 (could be IIS or ASP.NET), my first thought is that .net isn't registered with IIS, at least not the latest version.  If IIS is throwing the 404 it will look something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFX9W.jpg

If ASP.NET is working properly, the 404 will look something like this:https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECCxo.jpg

If you are getting the 404 from IIS, try re-running aspnet_regiis.exe -i.  On my windows 8 system the path is located here: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe"

More details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I get the second error.  I ran the update command you advised, but I still get the 404.  This same site is running fine on another server running 2008r2, so I'm sure it's a settings issue with IIS.

Answer (score 1):

By Default on Windows 8, the IIS will not install ASP.NET so go to "Turn Windows Features On/Off" and under IIS check-> World Wide Web Services-> Application Development Features-> ASP.NET 4.5

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

As basic as this sounds, if the `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` and IIS Directory Permissions don't solve your problem...try a full wipe and redeploy of the site.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install the "IIS Client Certificate Mapping Authentication" role service for IIS in order to clear out this error. My site is configured with client certificate authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you describe. I searched for a long time on different resources and tried everything I could. But the solution was so simple...

I opened Global.asax.cs, put the code in method  "Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)" in try_catch block. Then I  attached my project to w3wp.exe and put a breakpoint at  in Global.asax.cs. I rebuilded the webApp and tried to call my site from the browser. When I hit the breakpoint I pressed F5 and got the error message in my Catch block.

My problem was in some missing dlls, though the project would built without any warnings or errors. Also, I had a reference to NPGSQL and to some my other dll that has a reference to NPGSQL. And the version of NPGSQL in WebApp was different from the version in my other dll. So that caused the problem too.

Just try to debug the start of your web application, hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check site bindings in IIS.  Make sure you are not binding to a system port or other port that may be in use, causing a collision.  Generally, higher-numbered ports are less likely to be in use.

List of port # assignments:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers
https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml